# Add atomic doubles

Tags: java, double, atomic

There is a note at the end of the [atomics package summary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) that states:

> ... You can also hold `floats` using `Float.floatToIntBits` and `Float.intBitstoFloat` conversions, and `doubles` using `Double.doubleToLongBits` and `Double.longBitsToDouble` conversions.

Obviously you cannot just add these values together so what would be the equivalent to the atomic `addAndGet` for a `double` value.

```
private AtomicLong sum = new AtomicLong();
...
// This would almost certainly NOT work.
public long add(double n) {
  return sum.addAndGet(Double.doubleToLongBits(n));
}
```

You can assume I am trying very hard NOT to use `synchronized`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guava provides [`AtomicDouble`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.html), and using that is probably the simplest thing to do, rather than rolling it yourself...

That said, it's internally implemented with a wrapper around `AtomicLong`, you can see their implementation of `addAndGet` [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.html#line.184); it's basically

```
while (true) {
  long current = value;
  double currentVal = longBitsToDouble(current);
  double nextVal = currentVal + delta;
  long next = doubleToRawLongBits(nextVal);
  if (updater.compareAndSet(this, current, next)) {
    return nextVal;
  }
}
```

which is really the only way to do it without dealing with assembly.

Full disclosure: I work on Guava.

Comment: Ah yes! I can see how that would be the only way without going to JNI and assembler. Could you post the solution here as code for completeness please? Just the `addAndGet` would be sufficient.

Comment: Although starvation can be a problem in theory here, I guess it doesn't really occur in practice.

Comment: There are more sophisticated solutions that give up perfect atomicity -- for example, if you're just using it as an "adder" -- if you only add and get, without any explicit sets -- something like [Doug Lea's `DoubleAdder`](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/jsr166e/DoubleAdder.java?revision=1.2) can improve concurrency at the expense of non-atomic `get` calls.